# Magento 2: How to rename "add to cart" text on catalog page only

Tags: addtocart, magento2.3.1, edit

I'd like to rename the "Add to cart" button to "View now" on the catalog page and homepage only. However on the product view it should still state "Add to cart".

Which js files do I have to edit in order to achieve that?

Comment: for homepage check with file, which is loaded

Answer (score 0):

For homepage check with which file are you using.

for product list page override js file from path

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

to

`app/design/frontend/themename/packagename/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

you can changes text which you want to from this file.

Comment: I don't really understand your solution, could you elaborate? I am not so experienced so a step by step guide would be very useful.

Comment: first goto vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js and copy this file, than paste here - app/design/frontend/yourthemename/yourpackagename/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js than find 'Add to Cart' text and than replace.